# How do I calculate the position $x(t)$ for a given initial position $x_{0}$ and initial velocity $v_{0}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's given differential equation $mx''+rx'=−mg$.

This equation describe the movement of a falling body under the influence of gravitation and friction.

**a)** Find the differential equation as the first-order system for $x(t)$ and $v(t):=x′(t)$.

$v(t)=-g/r+Ce^{-rt/m}=x'(t)$

**b)** For which $v_{0}∈R$ exists one $T$ with $v(T)=0$?
$v=v_{0}, t=T=0$

$T=-\frac{m}{r} ln(\frac{g}{rv_{0}+g})$

$v_{0}\neq-g/r$

**c)** Give $T$ as a function of $v_{0}$.

Is this the same as b) ?

**d)** Calculate the position $x(t)$ for a given initial position $x_{0}$ and initial velocity $v_{0}$? The resulting integrals doesnt need to be calculated.

Can someone help me with c and d?

Comment: $T=\frac{m}{r}ln(   \frac{rC}{g})$

Comment: But from excatly what I can get that and where is v0?

Answer (score 1):

The position $x(t)$ is the primitive of velocity $v(t)$,  so

$x(t)=x_0+\int_0^t v(t)dt$

$=x_0-\frac{g}{r}t+C\int_0^t e^\frac{-ru}{m}du$

$=x_0-\frac{g}{r}t+C\frac{m}{r}(1-e^\frac{-rt}{m})$

Comment: What about c) ? Is that the same as I did b)?